# SQL Server stored procedure loop through records processing all columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm transitioning from Oracle to SQL Server and I am struggling to find an answer to a seemingly simple task.

In all databases, `select *` will return an entire row.

In Oracle you can treat the entire row as a structured record which was great for tables with lots of columns (say 30).

Everything I've seen has SQL Server only being able to select into defined columns when looping. With lots of columns that's impractical and just creates massive development overhead and too much code clutter.

I'm hoping it's merely a limitation in my googling..

In Oracle if I wanted to loop through every record in a table I could do this...

```
begin
    for rec in (select * from some_table) loop

        dbms_output.put_line(rec.column1)
        ...
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.columnx)

    end loop;
end;
```

Crazy simple.

How do I do this as easily in T-SQL?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Typically in T-SQL, we avoid cursor or loop. It is not efficient

Comment: A SMALL sample and desired results would be most helpful

Comment: I'm trying to achieve not having to create variables for 30 columns with typing and then having to type them again in the select and the fetch

Comment: An example would be to print out the information_schema.columns table as pipe "|" delimited text but it could be anything.

Comment: actually don't use that example. You could do that in a select. Actually use it but each numeric datatype needs to be printed in reverse order.

Comment: Without sample output it's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. It _looks_ like for a table with 10 rows, the output in your code sample would output 20 rows (albeit not in a tale as such). Is that right? (two rows per source row). To achieve that specific requirement in T-SQL I would cross join with a two row table then use `IIF` or `CASE` to pick out which column showed on which row. Yes this is overly verbose. You can make it even more verbose by insisting that a cursor be used. No there is no concept of `ROWTYPE` in SQL Server.

Comment: "How do I do this as easily in T-SQL?" You don't, because cursors suck. This is just another reason why. T-SQL only has `FETCH .. INTO`, and you'll have no choice but to declare and write out all the variables. "Code clutter" is pretty much par for the course in T-SQL; writing procedural code in it should be avoided whenever possible.